# iTextSharp - Using Annotations for Redlining

Tags: pdf, annotations, itext

I am creating a PDF document using iTextSharp, and I need the document to show which paragraphs have changed since the previous version, and a way for the user to view the previous version of the paragraph, with the following restrictions:

1) Document has to look good (I'll define that better in a second) in Windows Adobe Reader, Mac Adobe Reader, and Mac Preview.

2) Either:

2a) The "redlining" is invisible normally (and appears only when the mouse moves over the part of the document that changed, or when the appropriate menu option is selected), or

2b) There is an easy way for a Mac user to make a copy of the PDF in which the redlining is removed or invisible.

If I create annotations in my PDF document, 2b) is possible by opening the PDF in Mac Preview and doing a "File:Print:Save as PDF" which creates a new copy of the PDF without annotations.

But then I run into with 1), making the document look good.

Right now I'm adding annotations to the title that appears above the paragraph, which is being created like this:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk("Paragraph Title", font);
Paragraph pargTitle = new Paragraph(c);
section.Add(pargTitle);
Paragraph pargContents = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Paragraph contents", font));
section.Add(pargContents);
```

For testing, I'm creating seven different types of annotations:

```
/* A1 */ section.Add(new Annotation("Section Title", "Section Text"));
/* A2 */ pargTitle.Add(new Annotation("Paragraph Title", "Paragraph Text"));
/* A3 */ PdfAnnotation ann = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(doc.Writer, null, "Chunk Title", "Chunk Contents", false, "Comment");
         ann.Color = BaseColor.YELLOW;
         c.SetAnnotation(ann);
/* A4 */ c.SetAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreateText(doc.Writer, null, "Chunk Title", "Chunk Contents", false, "Comment");
/* A5 */ c.SetAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreatePopup(docWriter, null, "Chunk Popup", false);
/* A6 */ c.SetAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(doc.Writer, null, "Chunk Stamp", "Chunk Name"));
/* A7 */ c.SetAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreateSquareCircle(doc.Writer, null, "Chunk Stamp", true));
```

None of them consistently satisfy requirement 1) (document has to look good).

Windows and Mac Adobe Reader:

```
A1: Looks good, annotation indicator appears to left of paragraph
A2: Looks good, annotation indicator appears to right of paragraph
A3 and A4: Annotation indicator overlaps paragraph
A5: Doesn't show up
A6: Annotation indicator is a box with diagonal lines that completely
    overlays the paragraph title
A7: No annotation indicator, but when mouse hovers over the paragraph
    the annotation appears.
```

Mac Preview:

```
A1: Shows up as a solid black square to the left of the paragraph
A2: Shows up as a solid black square to the right of the paragraph
A3: Shows up as a solid yellow square overlapping the paragraph
A4: Shows up as a solid black square overlapping the paragraph
A5: Don't show up
A6: Doesn't show up, but when mouse hovers over the annotated paragraph
    it turns into a mickey mouse glove
    and when you click, it draws eight blue circles at the corners and midpoints
    but the annotation text is unavailable
A7: Doesn't show up, but when mouse hovers over the annotated paragraph
    it turns into a mickey mouse glove
    and when you click, it draws eight blue circles at the corners and midpoints
    and you have to resize the rectangle to see the annotation text
```

It's also unpleasant that if I pick "View:Highlights and Notes", Preview crashes.

I like the discussion in [this forum](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/11635.page) but the site it refers to (itext.ugent.be) is offline, so I can't see what clever things that author had come up with.

I'll throw in another twist: in order to generate a nice table of contents, I create all my paragraphs and sections prior to adding them to the document, and then add the chapters to the document once they've all been created, which I assume causes some issues since I don't know the location of the Paragraph at the time I'm constructing it.  Maybe I have to use a PdfTemplate to create my annotations as each page is constructed?

Comment: The [java file can be found here](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/examples/raw/e4ab68dbf43319d35990d74c944594d122aab187/src/in_action/chapterX/TooltipExample3.java).